# Query from checkboxes

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have the following tables in my mysql databases. I am trying to create an application that can virtually asses if someone may be developing cancer of the oesophagus

```
#tblsymptoms - holds all symptoms
######################################
symptomID  | symptom    
-------------------------------------
1            Mass in the throat        
2            Difficulty in swallowing   
3            Lost weight lately
4            Heartburn
5            Hoarse-sounding cough
6            Vomit blood


#tblresponse - holds all responses
######################################
responseID  | response   
-----------------------------------------------------
1            Your symptoms suggest you have a problem       
2            You may be having Oesophageal carcinoma  
3            You dont have a throat carcinoma


#tblrelation - holds relation between response and symptoms
######################################
relationID  | responseID | symptomID
-----------------------------
1         1          3
2         1          4
3         1          5
4         2          1
5         2          2
6         2          3
7         4          2
8         2          5
9         2          6
10        3          3
11        3          4
```

I want to use check boxes in the html form to query the database and here is the code for the form:

```
<form method="post" action="process.php">
<INPUT TYPE=CHECKBOX NAME="option[]" VALUE="Difficulty in swallowing" id="">Difficulty in swallowing<br>
<INPUT TYPE=CHECKBOX NAME="option[]" VALUE="Difficulty in swallowing" id="">Difficulty in swallowing<br>
<INPUT TYPE=CHECKBOX NAME="option[]" VALUE="Lost weight lately" id="">Lost weight lately<br>
<INPUT TYPE=CHECKBOX NAME="option[]" VALUE="Heartburn" id="">Heartburn<br>
<INPUT TYPE=CHECKBOX NAME="option[]" VALUE="Hoarse-sounding cough" id="">Hoarse-sounding cough<br>
<INPUT TYPE=CHECKBOX NAME="option[]" VALUE="Vomit blood" id="">Vomit blood<br>
<input type="submit" name="formSubmit" value="Diagnose me" />
</form>
```

Now, Just in case someone has selected: `Lost weight lately and Heartburn` the script should fetch data from tblResponse>>>responseID=1 and display to the user: `Your symptoms suggest you have a problem.`

I have tried but it returns 0 values

```
SELECT tblresponse.response
FROM tblrelation 
   LEFT JOIN tblresponse ON tblrelation.responseID = tblresponse.responseID
WHERE tblrelation.symptomID = '3' AND tblrelation.symptomID = '4'
```

Anyone with an idea on code that i should add to the html form with check boxes to query the database?

Answer (score 0):

One column can't have multiple values.  Try this:

```
SELECT tblresponse.response
FROM tblrelation LEFT JOIN
     tblresponse
      ON tblrelation.responseID = tblresponse.responseID
GROUP BY tblresponse.response
having sum(case when tblrelation.symptomID = '3' then 1 else 0 end) > 0 and
       sum(case when tblrelation.symptomID = '4' then 1 else 0 end) > 0
```

This groups all the relations together for a given response.  The `having` clause counts the number that are '3' and separately that are '4'.  If these are both greater than 0, then the response is returned.

By the way, if the IDs are numbers, you don't need the quotes.

Answer (score 0):

There is a design issue with #tblrelation.

The symptom of Hoarse-sounding cough will return both "a problem" and "You may be having Oesophageal carcinoma".

The combination of symptoms that result in a specific response need to be on a single row to establish the relationship as unique.

Tackle that before you do anything else, otherwise you'll never get the results your after.

You could create the table like this:

```
relationID  | responseID | symptomID
-----------------------------
1         1          3, 4, 5
```

but that would make for an ugly sql query when it came time to retrieve it.

If it were me, I think I would move that processing into the application. You could evaluate which boxes are checked and which are not and find the appropriate response without ever passing it to sql.

Comment: Thanks...i am confused..if you dont mind, please post for me how the table should look

Comment: If you can, it would probably be better to handle it within in the application rather than storing the relationship in sql

Comment: ok ...let me try that out...if you have an easier way that i may do it..you may post it here if you dont mund and i will actually appreciate..thanks again

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
SELECT response from tblresponse where responseID = (
SELECT responseID from tblrelation 
 where symptomID=4 or symptomID=3
 group by responseID
 having count(*) = 2
)
```

You need also to pass count all (number of selected values), in this case I used 2 which equal to (Selected options)

[DEMO](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/d142e5/7)

Edit: for 3,4, and 5

```
SELECT * from tblresponse where responseID = (
SELECT responseID from tblrelation 
 where symptomID=4 or symptomID=3 or symptomID=5
 group by responseID
 having count(*) = 3
)
```

[DEMO2](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/d142e5/9)

Comment: Looka at your query again: where symptomID=4 or symptomID=4 ....what if someone selected 3,4,and 5

Comment: @Nick: no problem, I corrected a typo in the query, and for 3,4, and 5 see this: [DEMO](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/d142e5/9) the idea here is to update count(*) = 3 also

Comment: @Nick: do you know what are the results for 1,2,3,4,5,6?!!

Comment: It returns zero rows. This is what it says: MySQL returned an empty result set (i.e. zero rows). ( Query took 0.0007 sec )

Comment: I am asking about true results what should query for 1,2,3,4,5,6 return?

Comment: Akam: I am posting a new quiz with screenshots. check it out.

Comment: it should return 2 >>>You may be having Oesophageal carcinoma

Comment: This is my last comment: check [this final demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/d142e5/36)